# How to convert a void * to CString

Tags: c++

Not much of a C++ developer and the multiple ways to handle strings always confuses me.

```
int Mine_SSL_Read(SSL* ssl, void* buf, int size)
{
    int length = Real_SSL_Read(ssl, buf, size);

    CString msg = ???
}
```

However I need to write a hook for SSL_Read function (OpenSSL) and that requires some C++ code. I need to convert buf which is of type void* and has a length of "length" into a CString so it can be parsed by other code.

Comment: What is the expected contents of the `void*`?  Is this just a buffer of `ASCII` or `UNICODE` characters?  Is it `NULL` terminated?

Comment: It is ASCII characters, null terminated (as far as I can tell OpenSSL docs are beyond horrible).  Answer awarded as your solution handles both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `void*` is simply one-byte (`ASCII` or similar) characters:

If you know it is `NULL` terminated, you can simply cast it:

```
// ASCII
CString msg = reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf);

// UNICODE
CString msg = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(buf);
```

If it is not `NULL` terminated, or you don't know that fact, then you have to copy it byte by byte (I don't believe `CString` has an `assign` function similar to std::string).

```
CString msg;

char* str_buf = msg.GetBuffer();
char* msg_buf = reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf);

for(int x = 0; x < size; ++x)
    *str_buf++ = *msg_buf++;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `reinterpret_cast`,

```
CString msg = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(buf);
```

Comment: This isn't a constructive answer; it depends on the format of the input data. Even if it's wcha_t*, what are the chances that it's null-terminated in the way CString would expect?

Comment: @tenfour: I have used OpenSSL before and it is char*, it is also null-terminated.

Comment: @Code Monkey: Gave a +1.  The code does work however for completeness I gave the answer to Chad's solution.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what's in void buff. if it's char* a simple cast and CString constructor it's sufficient, otherwise you should convert wchar_t* to char*. Be sure that buffer is null terminated.